# How to check user is logged in or not on non secure pages (http) if SSL (https) is active?

Tags: magento-1.7, https, ssl, secure

In header.phtml file using

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

we can check user is logged in or not.

If SSL is active on frontend then above function works fine if accessing page using https request but for all non secure pages using http request it fails.

How we can check user is logged in or not on all pages ie with http and https request in header.phtml?

Comment: The code you mentioned should work independent from the protocol you are using. If it doesn't work for you it may mean that you may have an issue with the session management. For example, the welcome message in the header is shown depending on the state of the customer (logged in or not) and it works on a default installation. Check `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header::getWelcome()` for confirmation.

Comment: Nice thought - the welcome block is a really good example of the logged in layout handle.

Comment: welcome block is not working even if cache is disable.

Comment: Then my bet is on a server problem, mostly on a session management issue.

Comment: It will really helpful if you describe little bit in detail.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea how to explain what it could be. I'm not even sure that's the problem. I'm shooting in the dark here. That's why I said 'most probably'.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for all page types - my guess is a cached block. Try the following:

- Append `?no_cache=true` to the end of your HTTP-only url
- Disable all caches and retry
- Relocate your check to another region - e.g. place it in `page/3columns.phtml` to verify that it is working as expected.

Comment: I tried all above your suggestions even welcome block suggested by Marius but still not working...

Comment: I am not using any other domain for https. My current settings for secure and unsecure URL are as follows unsecure: http://domain.com/ and secure: https://www.domain.com/ will this www secure URL will make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your session cookies are accessible via both http and https.

You will need to enter in `.domain.com` in Magentos `admin->system->configuration->web->cookie domain`. You will need to make the cookie available to your other domains in order for it to be read.  This is the same with all web applications.

Reference:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/web#session_cookie_management_field_descriptions

Comment: I am not using any other domain for https.
My current settings for secure and unsecure URL are as follows
unsecure: `http://domain.com/` and secure: `https://www.domain.com/`

will this `www` secure URL will make any difference?

Comment: Yes, the missing www from http could be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you are still in need for the question to be answered, but may be any new visitor may find it answering to concerning issues.

Such issues usually come up with cookie settings sometimes. You can change the settings from

> System > Settings > Web > Session Cookie Management

And set the value for 'Use HTTP Only' to No and save, afterward clear cache and test.
 Hope this helps.